# Yii2 Разделяем form-field

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii2

Вообщем есть обычная форма на yii2 для создания товаров, там есть пара инпутов где данные записываются в таком виде "20;30;40;60", он так и в базе хранятся, мне надо их как-то разделить чтоб каждый из них выводился в своём инпуте. Как разбить с помощью php я знаю, но как вот их правильно вывести?

Comment: Как правильно вывести? Делите "20;30;40;60" на массив, и в на форме в цикле выводите инпуты, давая им разные `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить все в массив и записать циклом через `->save()` или же если не использовать `AtiveRecord` воспользоваться `batchInsert()`